# twitter API variable in ExpressJs in scope AngularJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter

I use this twitter package from github "twit" to call the twitter api. I can read the data in the console.log but how do I pass this to AngularJs so that I can make the tweets visible in front-end.

```
T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'baby since: ${date}', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define an endpoint on your server the sends the response:
// Require 'twit' module here
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var PORT = 5555;

```
app.get('/tweets', function (request, response) {
  T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'baby since: ${date}', count: 100 }, function (err, data) {
    response.send(data);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port: ', PORT);
});
```